# Datagrid not insert data with observable collection Local

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

im Using Mvvm Pattern With wpf and Ef Code First

I have a WPF DataGrid bound to an observable collection in an MVVM application For Insert And Update Data To DataBase.and implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in viewmodel and model

when i Use observable collection Local without Filter Save Data To DataBase

but when Use "Where" Filter Not Insert

this property Create New Instance model When Add New Command;

```
public TypeTable TypeTableData { get; set; }
```

Entity is dbset

```
   public readonly IDbSet<TypeTable> Entity;
```

this observable collection filter Rows to show data in datagrid

```
public ObservableCollection<TypeTable> _List;
    public ObservableCollection<TypeTable> TypeList
    {
        get {Entity.load; _List= new ObservableCollection<TypeTable>(Entity.Local.Where(x => x.name== "MyFilter"));
            return _List;

        }
        set
        {
           if (_List!= value)
            {
                _List= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TypeList");
            }
        }
   }
```

this work perfectly and show list in data grid but when Add new Row to grid and save to data base not work And Save Null In Database

but when i use this ObservableCollection with Local fine work and insert Row to database

```
 public ObservableCollection<TypeTable> _List;
    public ObservableCollection<TypeTable> TypeList
    {
        get
        {
          Entity.load;  _List= new ObservableCollection<TypeTable>(Entity.Local);
            return _List;

        }
        set
        {
            if (_List != value)
            {
                _List = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TypeList");
            }
        }
    }
```

this is Add new ,save command that with RelayCommand Call In View :

```
  public void DoSaveBank()
    {


        Entity.AddOrUpdate(TypeTableData);
        Context.SaveChanges();

    }

    public void DoAddNewBank()
    {

        TypeTableData = new TypeTable();
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TypeTableData");
    }
```

this is Xaml code

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding TypeList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Path=TypeName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

how to resolve this problem?

thank you

Comment: i solved this problem , i should execute where in load, Entity.Where(x => x.name== "MyFilter").load